# Spatial file attribute table shows null after joining CSV file

Tags: attribute-table, csv

While I join a data table (saved as CSV) and added as both ways- 'delimited Text layer' and after that as 'new vector layer'.

After matching layer, the data shows null in the spatial attribute file. An earlier version used to join it without hassle.

After following some tips, CSVT seems to be a solution but generating a sidecar file

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. Which GIS software are you using? Also, can you provide screenshots of what your are trying to join to one another so we can better assist in your question.

Comment: I am using Qgis 2.18.13

Comment: Without seeing the screen shots of the data, I would assume the first thing to check would be the fields that you are joining to be of the same type as well as that you have matching attributes to be joining to one another.